How to Implement Consistent State Management in a Python GUI Framework Similar to Flutter?
I'm working on a custom GUI framework in Python that aims to mimic the behavior and experience of Flutter. The framework uses HTML and CSS for rendering the GUI inside a PyWebView window, targeting desktop platforms.
One of the key features I want to implement is state management that provides a similar experience to Flutter's StatefulWidget and State. My goal is to ensure that each widget retains its unique ID across the framework, so the state updates and UI re-rendering are consistent and smooth, just like in Flutter.
Current Setup
Widget Registration: I have a widget registry that stores all widgets with their IDs. This allows me to retrieve and update widgets consistently.
State Management: I have a State class where I call setState() to trigger UI updates. The widget IDs are generated when the widgets are instantiated and registered in the framework.
Problem
The issue I'm facing is that sometimes the widget IDs change during re-renders, which breaks the consistency of state updates. I want to ensure that once a widget is created and registered, its ID remains the same throughout its lifecycle, allowing for reliable state management and UI updates, just like in Flutter.
Code Snippet
Here's a simplified version of my widget and state classes:
import uuid
import weakref

class Widget:
    _framework_ref = None

    @classmethod
    def set_framework(cls, framework):
        cls._framework_ref = weakref.ref(framework)

    def __init__(self, widget_id=None):
        framework = self._framework_ref()
        if framework:
            if widget_id and widget_id in framework.widget_registry:
                self._id = widget_id
            else:
                self._id = str(uuid.uuid4())
                framework.register_widget(self)
        else:
            self._id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    def widget_id(self):
        return self._id

    def to_html(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Each widget must implement the to_html method.")


class State:
    def setState(self):
        self.update_existing_widget()

    def update_existing_widget(self):
        widget = self.framework.get_widget(self.widget.widget_id())
        updated_html = widget.to_html()
        widget.update_html_content(updated_html)


What I Need Help With
I'm looking for advice on how to maintain the widget ID consistently across the framework so that state updates are reliable and mimic the Flutter experience. Specifically, I need:

Best practices for ensuring consistent widget IDs across re-renders.

How to structure the State and StatefulWidget classes to achieve the desired behavior.

Any potential pitfalls or considerations when trying to replicate Flutter's state management in a Python framework.


Additional Context

The framework is similar to Flutter but is built with Python instead of Dart.

The GUI is rendered in a PyWebView window using HTML/CSS.

The goal is to provide developers with a seamless experience, with stateful and stateless widgets behaving just like in Flutter.


Github
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
